# "Many users subscriptions management" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subscription

I would like to let one user add other users to his/hers subscription. Currently doing it by just having one-to-many between subscription and users.

But I am looking for a gem that has already implemented adding users, removing users, suspending users from subscription, managing access to this subscription only by its owner, adding owners to this subscription and generally everything to manage adding more user to the same subscription.

Has anyone used such a gem?

Edit:
Koudoku is not the answer because it does:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Added by Koudoku.
  has_one :subscription
end
```

and the user has one subscription

Comment: Please Google a little before asking. https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku

Comment: Wow, thats great. I should have thought about searching on the Internet myself. Would definitely do it next time.. Except for when I google it the koudoku has
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Added by Koudoku.
  has_one :subscription

end
which seems to be different from a "Many users subscriptions" question

Comment: That comes from Rails 5. Don't worry about it if you're using another version of Rails.

Comment: @HassaninAhmed what comes from Rails? Could you provide a link with description?

Comment: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/12/28/application-record-in-rails-5.html

Comment: @HassaninAhmed, how does this blog post answer the question? It is totally unrelated or I can not see the relation?

Comment: What is your question now? This was from 4 months ago.

Comment: it is still the same -  "I am looking for a gem that has already implemented adding users, removing users, suspending users from subscription, managing access to this subscription only by its owner, adding owners to this subscription and generally everything to manage adding more user to the same subscription"